# Mount an existing RAID 1 Logical Volume after OS upgrade

Tags: linux-mint, raid, software-raid, raid1

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to Mint 16. The installer did not detect my existing RAID 1 array, and I can't access it anymore.

My drives are:

```
SDA - First RAID Disk
SDB - Second RAID Disk
SDC - Non-RAID where the OS is installed.
```

The disks are full of stuff I want to keep, so I don't want to create a new RAID.

On the old machine, the two raid drives became MD0, which was a physical disk for Logical Volume Management.

How do I put the two halves together and get it to mount at boot? (I know how to mount single drives and how to add fstab entries for single drives, but the part I don't know is how to mount the two drives as one disk as a RAID.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

First, I installed mdadm.

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm
```

Then I added an entry to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` (copied from the old system).

Then I ran `mdadm --assemble /dev/md0`.

Once that was done, `lvdisplay` showed my volume, and I could mount it with `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: from the mdadm manpage: `mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`