# OS and addtional software raid is it a good approach?

Tags: raid, software-rec, raid1

A friend of mine wants to use a root server for his wordpress pages.
His idea is to use one SSD as main drive for the OS and two HDDs for WWW-Root and database data.
The idea is to use both HDDs in a software raid 1 (mdadm).

SSD 256GB - OS

1 HDD 2TB – Software raid 1

2 HDD 2TB – Software raid 1

Is this a good approach?
If we have to switch the SSD (install new OS) in case of damage is it easily possible to mount the hdd raid again? I’m not shure in that case because the configuration of the raid was part of the OS SSD.
I found some topics about more or less the same constellation but it was never discussed is this a useful approach.
Could it make more sense to use hard disks with the same size and make a raid 5 overall inclusive OS?

Same topics - how to restore:
[How To Remount Raid 1 Array After OS Disk Failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466306/how-to-remount-raid-1-array-after-os-disk-failed)

[Mount an existing RAID 1 Logical Volume after OS upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108820/mount-an-existing-raid-1-logical-volume-after-os-upgrade)

Comment: You should always backup the RAID configuration. Without a copy of your exact config, your data would be lost. I would suggest you to have a look into ZFS first. It is in many aspects superior to a RAID.

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO: it falls under best practice to separate OS and application.
2. Not knowing the particulars of your OS I cannot say how hard it would be to recover your RAID setup, or if there are tutorials on howto recover.
3. If there are no tutorials - this could be a good opportunity for you to develop one.

- Install OS
- Install and Configure your Applications (e.g., web services, database) (I recommend keeping a copy of the configuration on the Application storage. Ideal would be not having any application configuration information on the OS disk.
- Power Off and Disable/Remove your Application Storage (to emulate a disaster).
- Re-install a fresh copy of the OS.
- Power Off and reconnect your Application Storage
- Work through the steps needed to get your Application recognized by the fresh install
- Work through the steps needed to get your applications running again
- Great Tutorial

Back to your question: separating OS and Application is considered "Best Practice" for High Availability. Going through the steps above prepares you for an efficient handling of a disaster!